# How can I create "evented" it tests in mocha

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I've written a series of tests in mocha for a node.js client/server application that uses UDP to send messages between the client and server.

My tests are mainly on the 'client side', treating the server as a block box and validating the responses from the server. The problem is that some of the "conversations" span multiple message send and receive events, sometimes going up to the dozens of seconds. It seems bizarre to have a 1,000 line test script with only one huge call to `it` at the top - I want to run multiple tests during the "conversation". I want more granularity in which specific parts of the test fail if it does fail (e.g. the first 2 responses from the server were fine but the 3rd was malformed), but the initial tests pass.

I've looked in to nesting the calls to `it` (doesn't seem to work) and most recently separating the calls to `it` in separate steps, with each step representing the sending or receipt of one message at the client side.

This approach doesn't seem to work because mocha terminates the node application after the very first step, never waiting for the socket to receive more responses from the server and complete the rest of the steps.

How can I create "evented" `it` calls in mocha?

The first would be called at the start of the test, then each successive `it` would only be called after receiving a response from the server. I'm looking for any solution that gives me the granularity on tests without having to write enormous functions in my `it` call that include dozens of messages between client and server. It's also not ok to attempt validating responses from the server outside of the context of a conversation where many messages have been sent and received before hand, because those messages determine the validity of the server response.

See a sample implementation that I created at https://gist.github.com/4490219. You can see the result is that the first test passes but the second is never executed even though the socket is clearly still open and waiting for requests from the server.

(P.S. apologies for the text formatting of the gist - I couldn't seem to select Javascript as a language type when creating it)

(P.P.S. I really don't want to have to use a series of setTimeout calls at the start of each step to make mocha think it has to wait).

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to use a combination of nested `it`s (which actually can be achieved if you use a `describe` between each nested `it`) and using a registration `it` with long timeout who's `done` is only called when a response arrives from the server.

For future googlers I created another gist to show the solution for this problem.

https://gist.github.com/Trindaz/4490646